# VB.NET - How to ad a My extension

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to access the My.Computer object in a class library project (Visual Studio CE). I know people say that I should find in Project Properties a "My Extensions" option - but it's just not there.

Microsoft site says the exact same thing but I just can't find that option.
*To access the My Extensions page, double-click My Project for your project node in Solution Explorer. When the Project Designer appears, click the My Extensions tab.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/my-extensions-page-project-designer-visual-basic?view=vs-2017

Besides that, Microsoft says the My.Computer should be available in Class Library project. Well, it's not. As a matter of fact My is totally empty.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/how-my-depends-on-project-type

LE:

- Visual Studio Community 2017 15.8.1
- .NET Framework 4.6.01055
- Class Library type: .NET Standard

ANSWER: .NET Standard Class Library does not have My extensions. Use .NET Framework Class Library when creating the project to be able to access My objects.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  Which class library project did you create:  `Class Library (.Net Standard)` or `Class Library (.Net Framework)`?

Comment: Answer in main post, thanks.

Comment: Try using `Class Library (.Net Framework)` instead.  When I created one using .Net Standard, it did not have the My Extensions tab, but creating one using .Net Framework did.  I'm not sure why there is a difference.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - thank you I have solved the mystery! In .NET Standard framework, the .net 1.4 version was used -> probably why My was empty. I have created a .NET Framework Class Library and works fine. So many thanks.

Comment: We were writing in the same time :) - thanks again.

Comment: In a WinForms project right click your project name in the Solution Explorer. Choose Properties all the way to the bottom on the context menu. Then choose My Extensions in the Project Properties.

Comment: @Mary - the issue here was that this option is not available when doing a .NET Standard class. Only with .NET Framework